# Prolog intersection of 2 lists of lists

Tags: prolog, intersection

I am trying to find the intersection of 2 different lists of lists. In other words, find out if all the lists in list1 intersect with any of the lists in list 2.

List1:

```
[[1,4],[1,6],[6,8],[8,10]]
```

List2:

```
 [[], [10], [8], [8, 10], [6], [6, 10], [6, 8], [6, 8, 10]]
```

I want to find an item in list2 where all the items of list1 intersect.
A solution would be `[4,6,8]`

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple implementation could be the following

```
intersect(L, M, E) :-
    member(E, M),
    maplist(intersect_(E), L).

intersect_(L, M) :-
    member(E, L),
    member(E, M).
```

Example queries:

```
?- intersect([[1,4],[1,6],[6,8],[8,10]], [[], [10], [8], [8, 10], [6], [6, 10], [6, 8], [6, 8, 10]], E).
false.

?- intersect([[1,4],[1,6],[6,8],[8,10]], [[], [10], [8], [8, 10], [6], [6, 10], [6, 8], [6, 8, 10], [4,6,8]], E).
E = [4, 6, 8] ;
E = [4, 6, 8] ;  % This succeeds twice because the list [6,8] has two ways of satisfying the predicate
false.
```

Comment: I don't want to check if its true or not, but rather which "M" item it is true for. So I believe there would be 3 parameters, one being the solution, the other 2 being the list. Also an explanation of how it works would be helpful for future references.

Comment: @shanmalic Fixed, but it's really the same. You just need to add `E` as an argument to `intersect`.